# IOS Authentication using a LAMP stack

Tags: mysql, ios, authentication, amazon-s3, ios7

I have a Cakephp app that runs on Amazon S3.  This app is the backend for my IOS app.  What is need to create a secure authentication from my ios register/login page to my MySQL page running on Amazon S3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very broad question with a lot of possible answers.  Token based authentication is a relatively simple option, and google has published a high level overview of that process.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps